# best way to link an input to a list

Tags: python, list

I need to write a part of my code which scans the input of a user , it firsts scans each group in the input then if the group is in one of the lists it prints a certain string is there a better way to do that than this way :

For se in inputt.split():
   If se in list:
      Print (a certain string)

There are a lot of lists to check so is there another way than having to repeat the if statement for each one ??

Comment: You need to provide sample input and sample output.

Comment: The inputt=raw_input("") , the code works but if i need to check like 20 lists do i need to write the if statement 20x if it prints a different string for each list ?

Comment: Map the name of the list to the string to output. Loop through the lists and if it is in a list, pull the string to print out of the map.

Comment: so i should make a dictionnary with all the lists and loop through that ? sorry if i dont get it still a beginner

Comment: oh sorry didnt see the exemple , thankd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dictionary:

```
lists = {string1:[list1], string2:[list2], ...}

for item in lists:
    if input in lists[item]:
        print(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just need to loop through your lists. If there is one string per list, how about a dictionary of the string to the list?

```
string1 = 'a certain string'
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']

string2 = 'b certain string'
list2 = ['d', 'e', 'f']

string_list_map = {string1: list1, string2: list2}

for se in inputt.split():
  for the_string, the_list in string_list_map.items():
    if se in the_list:
      print the_string
```

Comment: Thats what i did but since there is a lot of lists and each list has three strings i end up with a really long loop